# Update SQLite in travis CI

Tags: python, sqlite, travis-ci

On python 3.6 and 3.7 (django 2.2) I am getting 
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.8.2).`
On TravisCI

#### What I Did

- I tried installing it with addons:

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - travis-ci/sqlite3
    packages:
      - sqlite3
```

The sources here got ignored

```
Disallowing sources: travis-ci/sqlite3
To add unlisted APT sources, follow instructions in https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies#Installing-Packages-with-the-APT-Addon
```

- And with ppa in before_install

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:travis-ci/sqlite3
  - sudo apt-get -y update
  - sudo apt-get -y install sqlite3=3.7.15.1-1~travis1
```

error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:travis-ci/sqlite3'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

How can I get it to work?

Sources
https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-safelist/issues/368#issuecomment-198586476

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update your build enironment to [Xenial](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/xenial/). Trusty contains only [SQLite 3.8.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/sqlite3).

```
dist: xenial
language: python
...
```

[The full example of updating](https://github.com/inonit/drf-haystack/pull/136/files).